# how to use javascript to simulate mouse click

Tags: javascript, html, click, mouseevent

I have spent 2 days googling to find a cross-browser solution to simulate a mouse click on an html <*a*>, but have yet to find a one.

```
//-- REGARDING javascript's fireEvent (for IE browsers)
var lvs_event = 'click' ;              
var lvo_event = document.createEventObject();             
argo_target.fireEvent( 'on' + lvs_event , lvo_event );
//-------- does not work on either my winXP IE6 or my winVista IE8


//-- REGARDING javascript's dispatchEvent (for non-IE browsers)
var lvo_event = argo_target.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents') ;
lvo_event.initMouseEvent( 'click' , ... ) ;
argo_target.dispatchEvent( lvo_event ) ;
//-------- does not work on winVista FF3.6

//-- REGARDING inserting location.href
<a href    = '...'
   target  = '...'
   onclick = '...;location.href = this.href;...'
>
<script>
my_a.onclick();
<\/script>
//-------- works consistently BUT literally calls the onclick handler, ignoring all other <_a_> properties such as href and target

//-- REGARDING various jQuery solutions
$('#my_a').trigger('click');
//OR
$('#my_a').click();
//-------- does not work on any browsers (jQuery IS successfully being used for other features however)
```

MY GOAL: for a flash button mousedown to relay message to js, which in turns automates a <*a*> click process.

I can of course let flash call js, get the necessary html info from js and return it to flash, which can then do a as3 geturl, but I would prefer to tie into my existing html environment process.

I am currently testing using various versions of ff, ie, opera, safari(for win), chrome on winXP and winVista.

Comment: You can check out this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230308/automatically-press-keyboard-with-jquery/9230400#9230400 it should work in IE just fine. If not, what version of jquery do you use?

Comment: What do you mean by _simulate click_?

Comment: @elclanrs literally the process that begins when a user clicks a particular <_a_> ... if that particular <_a_> has various behaviors bound to its onclick handler, then those should be called. Likewise if that particular <_a_> has a target='_blank' then that should be observed.

BUT not merely calling its onclick-assigned handler

Comment: Oh, then `$('#my_a').trigger('click');` should work, don't know why it isn't working...

Comment: If solution from the link doesn't work, I would try with a newer version of jquery.

Comment: well, it seems that the caveat for jquery click() is usually that it only actuates the elements onclick handler, but ignores the <_a_>'s href and target attributes.

Comment: Then write a handler for this and simulate it using trigger.

Comment: @vucetica I am reluctant to change versions for backwards-compatibility concerns. Currently the site is heavily dependent upon the current 1.4.1 version.

Comment: but can you just make a quick check, to make sure if jquery version is a problem for this particular case?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to follow the url on trigger then you have to say so in the function:

**html:**

```
<a id="link" href="http://google.com">Link</a>
<a id="trigger" href="#">Trigger link</a>
```

**jQ:**

```
$('#link').click(function(){ alert('hey'); });
$('#trigger').click(function(){
    var $link = $('#link');
    $link.trigger('click');
    // window.location.href = $link.attr('href');
    window.open($link.attr('href'), '_blank'); // Popup blockers might block this
});
```

Comment: elclanrs, thanks for responding.

This however, does not truly simulate the process, but rather queries various features of the <_a_> and thus simulates those individual features. Which could work, but in my case it ignores the <_a_>'s target='_blank' requirement.

Comment: it should also be noted that this solution can be done, according to my testing, browser-safe using pure javascript: 
`my_a_tag.onclick()` 
along with the 
`location.href=my_a_tag.href`

Comment: lazy? I explained why your solution is not a solution after I tested it and determined what it does ... what part of that is lazy? Plus your solution ignores the target attribute ... see my original post.

Comment: I updated it with the target attribute! what I mean is that is so simple to do a google search for that.

Comment: elclanrs, you're wrong again ... window.open is the fundamental trigger for pop-up blockers ... web developers have been avoiding it since 2002.

Comment: I added the comment. But anyway, I don't know another way to do this. I don't think it's possible without using the actual anchor.

Comment: lol, sorry 'bout that, I guess it just enervates me that my answer is so simple... In the end, unless somebody else has a better solution, I don't think is possible to open a new tab or window without using an actual link. Can't the element triggering the link be another link? That would easily solve the problem.

Comment: originating action is coming from flash. And I could actually do this in flash, but I would prefer to tie in to the existing event flow that is already set up to handle that particular link (a facebook share button).