# Press escape key on keyboard with html button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

HTML button that when pressed simulates an ESC keyboard key pressed.
So clicking the button would have the same effect as user pressing ESC key on their keyboard

If it is certainly not possible in any way please tell me.

Any method is fine.

EDIT: I don't want pressing ESC key to trigger something, I want the reverse, something that triggers ESC key

Comment: You have an event that is listening to the ESC key and you want to trigger it? Is that it?

Comment: Dear you should read this answers carefully.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230308/automatically-press-keyboard-with-jquery

Comment: And what should pressing the escape button do? You can't simulate keypress events that are handled by the browser or operating system, only keypress events that are handled by javascript itself (or native events).

Comment: @Muhammad I dont understand the code in that link

Comment: Did You Check Any Of The Fiddle Below???

Comment: I think you have got solution in answers :)

Answer (score 4):

Try This Code

**JS**

```
$('body').keydown(function(e){
    if (e.which==27){
        alert("hh");
    }

});

$('#trigger').click(function(){
    var e=$.Event('keydown');
    e.which=27;
    $('body').trigger(e);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="trigger" value="trigger button" />
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/VmT2m/)**

Answer (score 0):

using JQuery you can Create `Key Press Event` and bind that Event with `Button Click`. Like:

```
<input type="button" id="esc" value="Esc like button">


<script>
$('body').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        // put your code here if any (that will run after Esc pressed).
        alert('Esc Pressed');
    }    
});

var e = $.Event("keydown", {
    keyCode: 27
});

$('#esc').click(function() {
    $("body").trigger(e);
});
</script>
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NikhilButani/gYW7D/)

Answer (score 0):

One can dispatch the keyboard event by creating an event instance and then dispatching it on the window.

```js
// following for keyboard key down event for "a"
const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {code: 'KeyA', key: 'a'})
window.dispatchEvent(event)
```

The point to note is that the event dispatched will not be a trusted event when listened.